# Regex to extract domain from website column

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regex-replace

I have a column called 'website' from which I require to extract the domain part only

Examples

1. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) -> google.com
2. [www.google.com/field](http://www.google.com/field) -> google.com
3. https://www.nearbyplaces.com -> nearbyplaces.com
4. http://hcc.ca -> hcc.ca
5. http://hcc.ca/info -> hcc.ca
6. http://hcc.ca/ -> hcc.ca

What I have done so far:

```
select distinct website, 
    CASE WHEN website like '%//www.%' THEN REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(website,'//[^/\\\,=@\\+]+\\.[^/:;,\\\\\(\\)]+'),'//www.','') 
         WHEN website like '%//%' THEN REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(website,'//[^/\\\,=@\\+]+\\.[^/:;,\\\\\(\\)]+'),'//','') 
         WHEN website is null then null
         WHEN website like '%www.%' THEN REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(website,'.([^/]*)'),'www.','')
         else website
         end as domain
```

Two Things:
I am certain that I am missing out on some of the test cases.
Secondly, I want to optimise the verbose in this solution.
Any help in improving my snippet is appreciated. (FYI I am using Redshift )

Comment: What about subdomains not called `www`? What about top level domains that have a second level hierarchy  such as `google.co.uk`? You shouldn't be parsing domains with RegExp. I'm not familiar with Redshift, but this looks like SQL and I doubt you can reliably do what you want with Regexp and SQL. You need URL parser library.

Comment: @RoToRa I went back to see if my current solution worked on second-level hierarchy and here is the current output:
```https://www.dakotabar.co.nz/ returns dakotabar.co.nz
https://www.law.cuny.edu/ returns law.cuny.edu```